# C++ Priority queue to find and modify objects

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I am trying to implement an A* algorithm and I need a priority queue, but the the `std::priority_queue` doesn't work for me because I need to find whether an element(a `Node` object) is in the `priority_queue` or not, to access its data and to modify it if necessary.

Can I do this using the `std::priority_queue` somehow?

I would appreciate code suggestions since I don't have much experience with `std::priority_queue`.

Comment: Can't you use front() and iterate through it?

Comment: what about boost::bimap ?

Comment: Note that the standard library containers usually avoid providing operations when they would be inefficient.  In the usual priority queue implementation (using a heap), search and membership test have O(N) complexity, which is probably why this operation is not provided built-in.  This may or may not be a problem for your application.  Just pay attention to how often you need to test for membership.

Comment: The search will have to be done at every new node, costing O(M), M=size of queue.

Comment: @AndréCaron Yes, it is going to be very inefficient but I need to prioritize the Nodes. Any ideas for something better than priority queue?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider [`Boost.Heap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/heap.html): "Mutability: The priority of heap elements can be modified."

Comment: @mariya: typically, when you need a membership test on a priority queue, you couple the heap with a (hash) set which implements this operation efficiently.  The cost is O(N) memory, so you can determine if this tradeoff is OK for you.  Make sure to add/remove items from the set each time you add/remove them from the heap.  If you want to implement removal, just remove the item from the set and ignore items that are not in the set when popping them from the heap.  If you need to update items, it gets slighly trickier, but it's also doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"but the the stl::priority_queue doesn't work for me because I need to find whether an element(a Node object) is in the priority_queue or not, to access its data and to modify it if necessary."*

You can well do this for any kind of class providing an appropriate `Compare` class parameter.

`std::priority_queue<T>` requires the underlying `Container` to comply with the concept of a [`SequenceContainer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer).

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

you can take the address of the `std::priority_queue<T>::front()` reference, and iterate through the queue, to find certain instances.

---

If you really need to have uniquely existent instances of objects, that should be managed additionally by some priority algorithm, it could be a good idea to store smart pointers (e.g. `std::shared_ptr<T>`), rather than values or raw pointers. The `Compare` class needs to be adapted appropriately of course.

---

```
struct CompareNodes {
    bool operator
        ( const std::shared_ptr<Node>& lhs
        , const std::shared_ptr<Node>& rhs
        ) {
        // Provide some operation to compare lhs < rhs (less) results in true
        // This function is meant to determine the actual priority of your Node
        // instances, when referenced in the priority_queue<> in question.
    }
};

std::priority_queue
    < std::shared_ptr<Node>
    , std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>>
    , CompareNodes
    > myQueue;
```

---

> *"to access its data and to modify it if necessary."*

Using the priority queue with `std::shared_ptr` as shown in the above sample, may also release you from even need to find instances in the queue, and *synchronize* data modifications from the original instance.

Comment: What should `value_type` be in `class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>`?

Comment: @mariya As for my sample `std::shared_ptr<Node>`. You have to implement this on your own, as I tried to demonstrate with `CompareNodes` in my sample.